# How to remove admin role permissions programatically?

Tags: security, user-management, user-profile

I tried changing it via

```
protected void RemoveRoles(User user)
    {
        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        {
            UserRoles.FromUser(user).RemoveAll();
            UserProfile profile = user.Profile;
            profile.SetPropertyValue("IsAdministrator", "False");
            profile.Save();
        }
    }
```

and

```
protected void RemoveRoles(User user)
    {
        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        {
            UserRoles.FromUser(user).RemoveAll();
            UserProfile profile = user.Profile;
            profile.IsAdministrator = false;
            profile.Save();
        }
    }
```

However, both functions throw an exception: "This property cannot be set for anonymous users." on line where I try to set IsAdministrator property.

The user object has correct values when I debug the code and I'm able to remove all the roles added via rolemanager. However, I'm unable to remove admin role from the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the correct code:

```
var user = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName("sitecore\\test", true);
RemoveRoles(user);

protected void RemoveRoles(Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user)
{
    Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserRoles.FromUser(user).RemoveAll();
    Sitecore.Security.UserProfile profile = user.Profile;
    profile.IsAdministrator = false;
    profile.Save();
}
```

The important thing is to pass `true` as the second parameter in the `FromName` method for the `isAuthenticated` parameter. Thanks to that you will be able to set `IsAdministrator` to `false`.